# Large amount of SSL clients in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, c#, ssl, activemq-classic

I've got a problem with a large amount (1000) of clients in ActiveMQ, using Failover protocol, SSL (NIO) and simpleAuthenticationPlugin. After some time of running the brocker just stopped.I've bee looking for some errors  in the log files, but I haven't found anything – it is empty.

server - ubuntu 15.04, java version "1.7.0_80"
Basic architecture information

I have a distributed system. It consists of C# Clients (nodes) and one Java Client (manager). I’m using ActiveMQ 5.12.1 installed on the same host where manager works. Communication takes place only between C# clients and the manager. C# clients don't communicate between each other.

Each client (C# and java) listens using one queue. When the manager wants to send a message to nodes, it does it using a unique queue. When one node wants to communicate with the manager, it sends a message to manager's queue. 
The manager polls every node each minute. Manager has 2 threads, one to receive messages. Second to pull nodes about informations

Here is the code:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory   connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("failover://(nio+ssl://localhost:61617)");
        connectionFactory.setUserName("user");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("password");
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        connection.setExceptionListener(this);
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination = session.createQueue("manager");
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
        Message message= null;
        while (!stop) {
            try{
            message = consumer.receive();
            if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                String text = textMessage.getText();
                processMessage(text);
            }
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Logger.getInstance().log("Exception in message receive loop continue");
            }
        }
```

Manager code to send a message:

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory   connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("failover://(nio+ssl://localhost:61617)");
        connectionFactory.setUserName("user");
        connectionFactory.setPassword("password");
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        while(!stop) {
            for (everynode) {
                    Destination destination = session.createQueue(uniqueNodeQueue);
                    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
                    producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
                    TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("in");
                    producer.send(message);
                    producer.close();
            }
            Thread.sleep(time);
        }

        // Clean up
        session.close();
        connection.close();
```

C# clients use Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ;

```
brokerUri="failover://(ssl://" +Server + ":61617?transport.acceptInvalidBrokerCert=true";
public NonDurableQueueSubscriber(string queueName, string brokerUri)
    {
        this.queueName = queueName;
        ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory(brokerUri);
        cf.Password = "password";
        cf.UserName = "user";
        this.connectionFactory = cf;
        this.connection = this.connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        if (this.connection.IsStarted)
            connection.Stop();
        this.connection.Start();
        this.session = connection.CreateSession();
        ActiveMQQueue queue = new ActiveMQQueue(queueName);
        this.consumer = this.session.CreateConsumer(queue, "2 > 1", false);
        this.consumer.Listener += new MessageListener(OnMessage);
    }
public void OnMessage(IMessage message)
    {
        ITextMessage textMessage = message as ITextMessage;
        if (this.OnMessageReceived != null)
        {
            this.OnMessageReceived(textMessage.Text);
        }
    }
static void onMessageReceived(string message)
    {
        NonDurableQueuePublisher mypublisher = new NonDurableQueuePublisher(queueManager, activemqBrokerUrl);
            mypublisher.SendMessage(info());
            mypublisher.Dispose();
    }
public NonDurableQueuePublisher(String queueName, string brokerUri)
    {
        this.queueName = queueName;
        ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory(brokerUri);
        cf.Password = "password";
        cf.UserName = "user";
        this.connectionFactory = cf;
        this.connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        this.connection.Start();
        this.session = connection.CreateSession();
        ActiveMQQueue queue = new ActiveMQQueue(queueName);
        this.producer = session.CreateProducer(queue);
    }
public void SendMessage(String msg)
    {
        if (!this.isDisposed)
        {
            ITextMessage txtMessage = session.CreateTextMessage(msg);
            //txtMessage.NMSPersistent = false;
            producer.Send(txtMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);
        }
    }
```

activeMQ.xml config activeMQ brocker

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core 

http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">


<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
      lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
      init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
</bean>

<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry topic=">" >

              <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
              </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>


    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>


    <persistenceAdapter>
        <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>

      <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>



<plugins>
<simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
<users>
<authenticationUser username="user" password="password" groups="users,admins"/>
</users>
</simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
</plugins>
<sslContext>
        <sslContext keyStore="/ssl/broker.ks"
                    keyStorePassword="password"/>
    </sslContext>
    <transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="nio+ssl" uri="nio+ssl://0.0.0.0:61617?maximumConnections=20000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>

    </transportConnectors>


    <shutdownHooks>
        <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
    </shutdownHooks>

</broker>

<import resource="jetty.xml"/>
```

Some cut interesting logs when I used NIO:

```
2015-11-25 17:20:31,495 | ERROR | Could not accept connection from null: java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack? | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-616
2015-11-25 17:20:31,495 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://192.168.1.4:51939 failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack? | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ NIO Worker 151
2015-11-25 17:20:25,493 | ERROR | Could not accept connection from null: java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-787
2015-11-25 17:20:19,309 | ERROR | Could not accept connection from null: java.io.IOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | ActiveMQ BrokerService[localhost] Task-669
2015-11-25 17:19:53,051 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://192.168.1.23:51587 failed: org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityIOException: Channel was inactive (no connection attempt made) for too (>30000) long: tcp://192.168.1.23:51587 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker
```

Before NIO I've tried only SSL, the result was the same → brocker shutdown.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be exceeding the maximum connections limit configured in your activemq.xml.  You can check the number of connections via JMX to confirm this.

You need to look into why your setup is creating so many open connections and why it is not closing them down if that is the intention.  The C# code looks a bit dodgy to me (no close calls any place) but since I can't see it all maybe it's fine.

This would not appear to be an ActiveMQ problem but an application problem.